# RESTLET -RPC CALL in GWT

Tags: gwt, restlet

I am new to restlet web service and i got to use restlet-rpc instead of gwt-rpc..I googled
around and found few sites like http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html and  [http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/144-restlet.html]  but nothing quite helped me.

Moreover org.reslet.jar of gwt http://www.restlet.org/downloads/stable does not support server methods(like ServerResource in restlet)!

A sample hello world with restlet-rpc in gwt, is what all i look for,so i understand the basics of restlet-rpc!Any help in regard with this would be appreciated!

Comment: restlet docs seem to be quite good, have you tried the given example http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/162-restlet/version/default/part/AttachmentData/data/RestletGWTSimpleExample.zip ?

Comment: Yes,i did try it(i have mentioned the example in my second link ),but it did not help me!

Comment: then be specific, what exactly doesn't work in that example?

Comment: sorry,it does not explain the rpc mechanism in that example!

Comment: all i look for is restless rpc-callback mechanism,probably with an example!

Comment: what makes you think restlet is about making RPC calls? the docs clearly say they prefer REST over RPC: "By default, GWT recommends using a custom GWT-RPC mechanism... As you know, REST is a much more flexible and interoperable way to communicate.."

Comment: and why would you use restlet if your goal is to do RPC calls, what's wrong with GWT's RPC?

Comment: The main reason for moving to restlet rpc is to avoid Cross site scripting which is possible with GWT-RPC!

Comment: using restlet doesn't guarantee xss is not possible. and you can prevent xss with GWT RPC by escaping input before returning it back to the client. have a look at SafeHtml for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're not sure what you need so why don't you try with GWT's RPC, and then GWT's RequestBuilder + your server side code that returns JSON, and then move to Restlet.

RPC and REST are fundamentally different approaches of client-server communication, and you want to shoehorn one into another without a good reason.

UPDATE:

> The main reason for moving to restlet rpc is to avoid Cross site scripting which is possible with GWT-RPC

Using restlet doesn't guarantee xss is not possible, and you can prevent xss with GWT RPC by escaping input before returning it back to the client. Have a look at [SafeHtml](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html) for example.